# 2 Different Values in 2 Cells

Tags: string, function

I checked other questions but I'm unable to find the one that fit what I need to do. I have 2 different cells. One cell has the complete data and the other is a code. I need to have a cell that will check these two cells and return true.

```
Example:
A2 = "Data Code English"
B2 = "DCE"
C2 = Should say "True" since DCE is a representation of Data Code English
```

DCE will be the code for Data Code English. Now the problem is, sometimes B2 may say DCS-T-DCE (or vice versa) meaning that the agent was transferred from DCS (Data Code Spanish) going to DCE (Data Code English).

```
Example 2:
A2 = "Data Code English"
B2 = "DCS-T-DCE"
C2 = Should say "True" since the agent not belongs to Data Code English
```

There are also many different codes that may be added in B2 but I think I'd be able to figure it out once I know how to do example 1 and 2.

Comment: What is that? Please, Can you tell us which is the platform what are you using (.net,java,etc)?

Comment: is this using a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

in case if this is excel try [type function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/type-function-HP010062400.aspx)